# How to write recursive query in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

can anybody help me to write a recursive query in sequelize?

I can able to write query direct in PostgreSQL database, but unable to write in sequelize

Comment: add more details to your question so other can understand your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to use `query` method of the Sequelize instance to execute a raw SQL query with `WITH RECURSIVE` as you already did directly.

```js
const results = await sequelize.query('WITH RECURSIVE <rest of the query here>',
  { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });
```